# IIS generates same Session.SessionID

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, web-applications, authentication

I have deployed two web applications on my IIS7.

The problem is, IIS is generating the same Session.SessionID if I request both application using the same browswer (different tabs).

This is causing some problem with ASP.Net user authentication, it is some how overlapping with each other and the flag "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" returns false whenever the user logs in on to the other site. It works fine as long as user is working on one of the site.

Please help me out, I cant seem to find the reason for this, I mean the session is application specific so why is sessionID from one web app is conflicting with the other.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

<s>They are running in the same **application pool**. Just *separate* the application pools.</s>

---

Problem is your browser is treating these applications the same. Session in ASP.NET is implemented by the **session cookie**. These need to have **different website names** so that they do not share the same session.

---

## UPDATE

This is how session cookie works.

<s>But one solution is to access them as `mysite.com/1` and `mysite.com/2`. That I believe should also work.</s>

Comment: As I updated, you need to have different website names for them. Access them using different website names for example `app1.mysite.com` and `app2.mysite.com`

Comment: Website name as in complete different domain name? like www.x.com and www.x.com/2 will not work?

Comment: No it won't work although it could under conditions. Session cookie is set for the website. You just need to check the cookies with fiddler to see what values get there.

Comment: It worked, i tried one with localhost and other one with my-pc. Is there a way I can avoid this, I don't want to change the domain name or add sub-domain. I tried creating different app pools, but that didn't help.

Comment: This is how session works in ASP.NET or any other web technology. But setting up aliases are easy if it is an intranet. Also for an internet it should be fairly easy. But see my new update.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked application pools, if you want to isolate web application you should define different application pools.

Answer (score 0):

Is each application running in a separate IIS Application? If they are, then the session will be separate, as Session is scoped to the AppDomain. If they are in the same IIS application, they are loaded in the same AppDomain, and will share Session.

In the same browser session (regardless of using tabs), the same Session cookie will be sent.

Comment: Hi I am having an issue because both websites are defined under the same IIS application. Is it possible to isolate the sessions of both the websites maybe by specifying a different sessionName in the web.config or specifying different machine keys?